# Office365 SMTP Issue in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

I am using Mailtrap to send emails from my Laravel app but I want to use Office365 SMTP but unable to do so: I am using following credentials

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MyOutlookUsername
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyOutlookPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=starttls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="Email"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Sometimes this "**Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username**" error is coming or "**Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully.**"

One thing I am not sure about is, which MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD I am supposed to put? Is it my outlook Username/Password or I have to create an application and use its credentials here?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to change the MAIL_ENCRYPTION to `tls` instead of `starttls`

If you're still facing issues, try setting the stream option in your `config/mail.php` file to tls:

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
    'tls' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

Run Optimize command to clear the cache

`php artisan optimize:clear`
OR
`php artisan config:clear`

Also, For the Gmail account, we need to create an app and use its secret key but I'm not sure about Office365.